# setAttribute a href in Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, setattribute

I got `href` of an element. After that, I subString,...to make a new `href` and want to set it back to element. But Selenium doesn't have `setAttribute` method

```
nextListByNumber = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='paginater']//*[text()='"+2+"']"));
String href = nextListByNumber.getAttribute("href");
int manualcode1 = href.lastIndexOf("MANUAL");
int manualcode2 = href.lastIndexOf("/sort");
String manualcode = href.substring(manualcode1, manualcode2);

String hrefNew = "http://localhost/jp/courseassign/course_assign_search_result/"+manualcode+"/sort:User.login_id/direction:asc/page:"+i+"?limit=20";
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript for this

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute(arguments[1], arguments[2]);", nextListByNumber, "href", hrefNew);
```

Comment: It doesn't work. When using your code, I used getAttribute("href") to check, but the link didn't change

Comment: @AnhPhan This is because you made the change, the driver read the original html, not the local one. It should redirect you to the new page.

Comment: Do we have any ways to JavascriptExecutor click href link automatically after we made that change?

Comment: @AnhPhan Just click it like any other element.

Comment: JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute(arguments[1], arguments[2]);", nextListByNumber, "href", hrefNew);
nextListByNumber.click();

But...I am still stuck